# Initialize Object with different parameters

Tags: javascript

Hello I have code which replaces `document.write`, makes a buffer and than pushes buffer into the document:

```
 var lazyLoad = (function () {

    var counter = 0
    var buffer = new Array()
    function work(options){ 
        window.d = document     
        var tmp_buffer
        d.write = d.writeln = function(s){  tmp_buffer += s}

        d.open = d.close = function(){}
        s = d.createElement('script') 
        s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript')
        s.setAttribute('src',options.url)
        d.getElementById(options.block).appendChild(s)

        s.onload = function () {
            buffer[counter] = tmp_buffer
            console.log(buffer[1])
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                d.getElementById(options.block).innerHTML += buffer[counter]            
            }, 0)
            counter++
       }
    }

    return {

            init: function (options) {

                var CONFIG = {
                url: '',
                block: ''
            }

                $.extend(CONFIG, options)

                random = $('#'+CONFIG.block).attr('rel')
                id = $('#'+CONFIG.block).attr('id').replace(random,'')
                id = id.replace('DIV','')
                size = id.split('X')
                ele_width = size[0] || CONFIG.width
                ele_height = size[1] || CONFIG.height

                $('#'+CONFIG.block).css({
                                        'width':ele_width+'px',
                                        'height':ele_height+'px'
                                    })


                $(window).load(function(){
                    if(options.adfox) {
                        random = $('#'+CONFIG.block).attr('id')
                        AdFox_getCodeScript(1, random, CONFIG.url)
                    }else{
                        work(options)
                    }
                })
            }

    }


})();
```

If I init it once:

```
lazyLoad.init({
        'http://test.com/test.js',              
         div1
})
```

But if I call it again with other parameters:

```
lazyLoad.init({
        'http://test2.com/test.js',             
         div2
})
```

First init wont work. `buffer` will be empty. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi. Shouldn't you pass an object literal `{url: 'http://test.com/test.js', block: div1}` as parameter of the init() function ? Do you get any error ? When do you call the init() ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

will overwrite the event handler. Try using:

```
$(function(){ 

 });
```

instead. I think it'll add an array of event handlers. I could be wrong though. Please let me know how it turns out.

Also, it doesn't look like you're defining "s" in the local scope. If you don't put "var" in front of a variable when you define it, it'll get created in the global scope.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Would you be able to expose a url so I could see the whole context?

Comment: I think the problem is with tmp_buffer. When you use it in the second closure (within the s.onload function), it overwrites the first one. Can you try to put tmp_buffer.divid.value instead of just the tmp_buffer variable? That is, create one serialized variable for each of the "onload" callbacks. So, when the s.onload callback is eventually invoked, it refers to the proper tmp_buffer data.

Comment: that is... imagine that when you set the s.src variable, it asynchronously makes a call to retrieve that javascript file... and say that call takes 100ms... by the time the call comes back, the second event handler has already attached the event handler... so, the tmp_buffer in the first event handler has already been overwritten by the second tmp_buffer before the first s.onload is called...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4864/discussion-between-rsboarder-and-homer6)